# Why is Ubuntu14.04LTS running beta version of GRUB?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, grubrescue

I wiped the data on my 2 hard drives of my rack server and did a fresh install of Ubuntu14.04 LTS minimal server and yet could not boot

I get the below error
Please see screenshot

[image]
[image]

Why is Ubuntu supposedly `LTS` version using a beta version of grub?!?

And how do i fix this issue?

Thanks

UPDATE: tried on another server and got this other error as well
A different server entirely

[image]

SO anyone knows way around this? I just need to install Ubuntu 14.04LTS becoming rocket science already! Again i wiped ALL data from the hard drives. Empy and fresh install..second server now..what is going on?!?

Comment: The error messages tell you that grub has no access to the modules (commands), so something must have gone wrong when installing the boot loader or setting up the partition scheme.

Answer (score 2):

"Why is Ubuntu supposedly LTS version using a beta version of grub?!?"

According to https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2014-January/037978.html [1] because "This represents a year and a half of upstream development, and contains many new features".

[1] found via http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/grub-2-beta-ubuntu-14-04-lts via googling `ubuntu beta grub`.

Comment: and how do i resolve this since the thing won't boot because they became so smart to use beta grub

Comment: That's a different question entirely, which you might want to submit.

Comment: how can i download an older Ubuntu14.04.01 LTS of something where it is not using that version of grub?

Comment: @babababa There's no 14.04 not really using that version of grub.  The issues you observe are unlikely due to the GRUB Beta issue.  The second issue in your post isn't even an error, it's just a grub prompt.

Comment: thats why you down vote my post..fun to you right? well if its not an error, then is that how you want your OS to boot to? i posted question obviously to get help on how to boot the OS and get out of that prompt

Comment: @babababa How are you setting up your server(s)?  Do they have RAID hard drives in them?  Are the UEFI boot systems?  There are many factors as to why you will be getting a `GRUB` prompt after installing Ubuntu.  It could be an error with the hard drive.  It could be that `GRUB` is installed on the wrong drive.  During setup, it can ask you what drive do you want `GRUB` installed to.  You should be choosing your boot drive.  If you run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) it can upload some helpful logs from your system that we can help you with.

Comment: I am a system engineer(over 7 years) so i know how to install OS and what drive is what..the 2 hard drives are not in RAID. I have installed linux on the same servers before and recently for that matter like few days earlier, but i notice every other time i try to re-install fresh, i get error and all that so i wiped the whole disks so there is no confusion, and then try to install fresh again and now this is the new batch of prompts....for now i will try the `boot repair` thing and see where that ends..thanks for your time